# Formatting Excel Power Query Table

Tags: excel, cryptography, format

I created an Excel Power Query that pulls cryptocurrency data from [coinmarketcap.com](http://coinmarketcap.com)'s API. I want to format this data, but it won't let me.

For instance, I want the price coloumn to have a `$` sign in front of it, but when I hit the `$` sign in Excel, it doesn't work.

How do I enable the formatting of this data?

Answer (score 0):

format the cell as Accounting Number